# getting data into iOS app - Architecture for handling the data

Tags: objective-c, ios, database-design, architecture, loading

I've got a pretty basic question concerning iOS apps: How do you get large amounts of data into an app? I know about plists which is they way I import data. But it is tedious to create these plists (I use excel and smultron to do that - is there a better tool to do this) and I believe not very efficient for very large data sets.

Once the data is loaded I use it in the app (and could possibly feed it into a core data db).

Secondly, I was wondering what would be a good set up architecture-wise to load the data. Currently I am doing that in each viewcontroller that I use. But I guess that can be done more efficiently and centrally. E.g. by having one class that loads all the data - DataLoaderClass - (or on request if data is not always required). However, that would imply that I would need properties for each set of data for each viewcontroller. It would be much easier if I could just declare some global variables that can be accessed by each viewcontroller but are filled by the DataLoaderClass.

Any advice or key concepts that I should look up?

Thanks for answering these newbie questions - which are nonetheless of fundamental importance to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a massive .xls file using Excel, then import it using [DHlibxls](https://github.com/dhoerl/DHlibxls). Or you could use make a cvs file.

Answer (score 0):

What i do when i have large data sets is i write a small OSX app that saves it all to a core data store. I then export this store into my app and use it as my core data store in the app.I would recommend *Core Data*.

Comment: Yes, Core Data is a viable option to handle the data. However, I am interested in how to get the Data most efficiently into Core Data. Or in other words what is a good way to write your small OSX app? So far I only worked with iOS.

Comment: its not to hard to create a OSX its the same framework as creating a iphone app. You just have to make sure the the scheme matches in both apps. [Example](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated)